# Como obter a data max() e min() no SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Como posso obter a data mínima e máxima de uma tabela?

Estou usando as funções min() e max(), mas não está retornando o valor esperado. Esse é um pequeno exemplo dos dados de data da minha tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE Dados_Vendas
    ([Data] varchar(29))
;
    
INSERT INTO Dados_Vendas
    ([Data])
VALUES
    ('2016-12-02 00:00:00'),
    ('2016/07/16 00:00:00.000000000')
;
```

Se eu tentar puxar o min() e max() de data dessa tabela, usando as conversões:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(Data, 10), 103)) AS Data_Minima
    , MAX(CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(Data, 10), 103)) AS Data_Maxima 
FROM Dados_Vendas
;
```

Obtenho como retorno um erro: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Qual o tipo de dado de seu campo `Data`?

Comment: Está como varchar.

Comment: Utilize a função `CONVERT` para converter seu campo para o tipo DATETIME. Provavelmente a string que representa sua maior data tem ou dia menor que 31 ou mês menor que 12. A ordenação de string é diferente da ordenação de um DATETIME.

Comment: Se o campo é varchar, o resultado é ordem alfabética e a solução é consertar a base de dados. Se tiver mais algum complemento além desse, você pode [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema (com descrição das estruturas). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: @Bacco editei a pergunta com um exemplo pequeno da base. Se estiver errado, deleto a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O resultado vem errado por causa do tipo de campo. Você deveria usar `date` ou `datetime` em vez de `varchar`.

Ele traz o `31/12/2015` como valor máximo pois o `3` é maior valor. Ele ordena o texto assim: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`

Acredito que isto pode ser algum sistema legado. Para trazer os valores corretos utilize o `SQL` abaixo, aonde eu transformo o campo para `datetime` pelo comando `convert(datetime, data, 103)`, aonde o `103` informa o tipo de formatação do campo ([Referência do comando convert](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)), e depois converto novamente para texto para apresentar no padrão `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
select 
  min(data),   
  convert(varchar(10), min(convert(datetime, data, 103)), 103),
  max(data),      
  convert(varchar(10), max(convert(datetime, data, 103)), 103)    
from 
  Dados_Compras
```

Ele está disponível em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c8d0f/3

#### Edição da resposta em 04/08/2020 as 22:39

Conforme comentário do usuário da pergunta, está ocorrendo o erro `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`, isto deve estar ocorrendo pois deve ter data inválida (com dia 31 em mês que somente tem 30 dias, mês acima de 12 e outras formatações). Isto ocorre por causa da utilização do tipo de campo inadequado para data, como já falei na minha resposta.

Para encontrar o registros com erro, rode o  `SQL` abaixo. Também atualizei o exemplo. Novo link [Resposta atualizada no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce700/2)

```
select 
  * 
from 
  Dados_Compras 
where 
  try_convert(datetime, data, 103) is null
```

Comment: Eu tentei converter o tipo de dado, mas ele retorna um erro "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: @Alineat atualizei a resposta e atualizei o exemplo no sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Converta o campo para o tipo **DATE**:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(Data, 10), 103)) AS Data_Minima,
    MAX(CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(Data, 10), 103)) AS Data_Maxima 
FROM Dados_Compras
```

Comment: Eu tentei isso, mas ele retorna um erro: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Tente utilizar o LEFT para pegar apenas os caracteres da data sem considerar o horário: LEFT(Data, 10), alterei na resposta para você testar.

Comment: Eu tentei com o LEFT e retorna o mesmo erro "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Se usa o tipo errado e coisas banais ficam complicadas...